# Why it is going in infinite loop

Tags: java, mongodb, user-interface, registration, netbeans-8

Here, 
what i wanted to do is that
if given userid already exists then it should clear all the fields.
and restart that page ....

```
private void uuserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    MongoClient mClient;
    DB mDB;
    DBCollection valCollection;
    Cursor cursor;

    try {
        mClient = new MongoClient(ip, port);

        System.out.println("Connected to mongodb instance at " + ip + ":" + port);
        mDB = mClient.getDB(dbName);
        valCollection = mDB.getCollection(collectionName);

        userid = uuser.getText();

        BasicDBObject findPara = new BasicDBObject();
        BasicDBObject findCon = new BasicDBObject();

        findPara.append("userid", userid);
        findCon.append("userid", true);
        findCon.append("_id", false);

        cursor = valCollection.find(findPara, findCon);

        flag = 1;
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            flag = 0;
            System.out.println("User ID is not correct!!!");
        }

        if (flag == 0) {
            System.out.println("User Id is not correct...");

            dispose();
            new Register().setVisible(true);
        }

        System.out.println("Move Forward Your Id is correct...");

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: "User ID already exists" would make more sense to print if the cursor contains any values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code never advances to the next record.

The loop should contain

```
cursor.next()
```

to consume the result.

Comment: Not sure why you are not using simply count, it will improve your coding standard

Comment: @RohitJain Indeed - and in combination with a first or limit, as the total count is not required. This only strives to address the literal question / problem.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you have to do something like this:

```
flag=1;
while (cursor.hasNext())
{
  cursor.next();
  flag=0;
  System.out.println("User ID is not correct!!!");
}
```

Because your cursor never move to the next Element.
Also I see no benefit in using a while-loop for you purpose.
In this case you wouldn't even need to advance your cursor,
if you only want to know whether there is no entry with that id or some.

```
flag=1;
if(cursor.hasNext())
{
  flag=0;
  System.out.println("User ID is not correct!!!");
}
```